# Manually trigger an event in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to manually trigger events like `on_message` or `on_command_error`?
Similar to manually raising a Exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, use the `Bot.dispatch` method (this is useful for creating custom events), note that you have to pass the arguments manually

```py
bot.dispatch("message", message) # You need to pass an instance of `discord.Message`
```

```py
bot.dispatch("command_error", ctx, error) # Remember to pass all the arguments
```

Example of a custom event

```py
@bot.command()
async def dispatch_custom(ctx):
    bot.dispatch("custom_event", ctx)


@bot.event
async def on_custom_event(ctx):
    print("Custom event")
```

There's no docs about it so I can't give you the link, if you want to know more about it take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L365-L403)

Comment: Oh wow thanks! Why is it not on the official docs?

Comment: I also didn't know it's possible to create a github link that highlights certain lines