# Python Discord Bot: How to imitate an action from an event listener "on_guild_join" to a command "refresh"

Tags: python, discord, command, bots, event-listener

I am creating a simple discord bot game. My `on_guild_join` function looks like this:

```
class BotEvents(commands.Cog):
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        do something
```

Now, I want to add a command `refresh` which will do a similar action with the `on_guild_join`

```
class BotActionCommands(commands.Cog):
    
    @commands.command()
    async def refresh(self, ctx):
        do same thing with on_guild_join
```

On my current code, i just copied everything and replaced `guild` with `ctx.guild`, but i'm wondering if there are better ways to do it. Maybe call the on_guild_join function inside the refresh command? But I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually trigger an event in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029666/manually-trigger-an-event-in-discord-py)

Comment: This is useful but in my case, i am still defining `refresh` command. The bot instance is not yet created. I cannot put `bot.dispatch('guild_join', ctx.guild)` inside the refresh.

Comment: Usually when people create cogs, they pass the bot as an argument to the constructor, and set it as an instance attr. If you do that, you can then use the bot with `self.bot`

Comment: Oh yeah, i revised the code to `self.bot.dispatch('guild_join', ctx.guild)` and it worked! Thank you!